# Android OOM(out of memory) in recyclerview using Picaso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is recyclerview adpater onBindViewHolder method , every time i make rquest , i get 10 elements add to List and notidify the dapater , thats working fine but after 4 or 5 calls my app crash when PICASO fetch image , and cause out of memory exception

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
    //okhttp client
     OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    //okhttp downloader
     OkHttp3Downloader downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(client);
     //picaso fetch the image  set to image view , width 500 ,height 100 
     picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader).build();
        picasso.load(recordList.get(position).getImageUri())
                .error(R.drawable.golootlo_placeholder_nearby)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.golootlo_placeholder_nearby)
                .fit()
                .into(holder.imageViewBanner);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }

    /*rest of view are getting value here from List object*/
}
```

Comment: try using  Glide instead, because picasso uses a larger footprint while loading images.

Comment: Glide and implement LazyLoad